# How should I autofit this Matlab plot?

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, scale

```
function [h,w,y,graph] = lowpassFIR(sample)

%Calculates Finite Impulse Response low pass filter coefficient
%using the windowing methods as well

passEdge = 100;
StopbandAtt = 20;
passbandRip =.05;
transWidth = 10;
Fs = sample;





%Step One: select number of coefficients%
deltaF = transWidth/Fs;

%Normalize for each window


rectN = round(0.9/deltaF);

hannN = round(3.1/deltaF);
hammN = round(3.3/deltaF);
blackN = round(5.5/deltaF);

rectN = 1:rectN

%rectPos = round(rectN/2);
%rectNeg = round((rectPos*-1));


%For the Vector Array
%rect = rectNeg:rectPos;

deltaSum= passEdge + (transWidth/2);
deltaF2= deltaSum/Fs;

h=zeros(size(1:rectN(end)));
w=zeros(size(1:rectN(end)));
y=zeros(size(1:rectN(end)));
graph = plot(y)
for i = 1:rectN(end)

   %iterate through each value and plug into function in for loop
   %each output of the function will be stored into another array
    h(i) = 2*deltaF2*(sin(i*2*pi*deltaF2))/(2*i*pi*deltaF2);   
    w(i) = 0.5 + 0.5*cos(2*pi*i/rectN(end));
    y(i) = h(i)*w(i);
    graph(i) = y(i);
end
```

From the code you can tell that I am trying to get the graph result from graph....but when it outputs, I get the values on the command window, but the figure shows a straight line @ zero...how do I auto scale the y-axis here??

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that auto scale is the issue here, but rather the sequence of events.

You try to "initialize" your plot in this line:

```
graph = plot(y);
```

However, in the previous line, you define

```
y=zeros(size(1:rectN(end)));
```

Therefore, the plot you see will be a straight line at `y=0`. The value of `graph` is the [handle to the line object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html), in this case your line of `y=0`.
After trying to set up the plot, you enter a loop and at each iteration, you add a value to your line handle (`graph(i) = y(i)`) - but you don't plot anything. If, after the loop, you look at the values of `y` or `graph` you see your new values - but they are never plotted.
I doubt you need a loop in this case, maybe try this instead:

```
I = 1:rectN(end);
h = 2.*deltaF2.*(sin(I.*2.*pi.*deltaF2))./(2.*I.*pi.*deltaF2);   
w = 0.5 + 0.5.*cos(2.*pi.*I./rectN(end));
y = h.*w;
graph = plot(y);
```

It is important to note the [element wise multiplication](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/times.html): `.*`

One last comment: You should not use `i` (or `j` for that matter) as an iterator, because they are also used as the [imaginary unit](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/i.html) in Matlab, which can generate issues if you needed either somewhere in your code.

Comment: @user2514874 How do you remove the loop? Do you use the code from my answer?